# cpanel new account goes to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: domain-name-system

all my domains and created account work fine, but this domain which i created yesterday, each time i visit it, it redirects from domain.com to domain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi.

so i deleted it and re-created it, still same issue.. deleted the dns, rcreated new dns, then did cleanup and deleted dns and recreated..

do you know how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

My complete guess without knowing more specifics like the domain and IP... is that the IP address that the domain resolves to is not the same as the one configured in WHM for this account.  Thus it's resolving to the default virtualhost instead of being caught by the proper virtualhost entry.

Alternately httpd.conf isn't set up properly for some reason.  Try running /usr/local/cpanel/bin/build_apache_conf

Comment: Domain being set up on a different IP than the dns was pointing to was my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If jrod's answer doesn't set you straight you might check the `$domainuser/public_html/.htaccess` file.

Answer (score -2):

You should change the cpanel release to Bleeding Edge and run upcp.

Comment: That would not fix this. If this is a production server RELEASE or STABLE would be the safer way to go.